# unable to map parameters from FromQuery in .net core web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

i have this action in my controller. But when i provide mapid. geoid or the list in body its not not mapped properly from query into the parameters.

Unable to figure out what's wrong with this action. I do have similar actions but they are found to be working properly.

Any help or pointers are welcomed.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Consumes(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(List<MapViewModel>), StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ProblemDetails), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ProblemDetails), StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ProblemDetails), StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateMap([FromQuery, Required] string mapId,
                                               [FromQuery, Required] string geoId,
                                               [FromBody, Required] List<MapViewModel> mapsList)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Query name must match with [FromQuery] paramater name. Your query must contains mapId and geoId  (I is upper case).

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly there was no issue with the code. What i came to know is in my above skeleton code if the parameters are not is use then values from FromQuery are not mapped.

But when i just did var a = mapId;  then parameter of mapId started showing value from FromQuery.